# When Kobie goes to school, he walks half the time and runs half the time.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When Kobie goes to school, he walks half the time and runs half the time. When he comes
home from school, he walks half the distance and runs half the distance. If he runs twice as
fast as he walks, find the ratio of the time it takes for him to get to school, to the time it takes
for him to come home from school.

I tried messing around with the distance formula and got that the walking speed is 2/3 (not sure if this is correct), but 
I am not sure how to go on frome here.

Comment: 2/3 of what? The best things you can do to start a problem like this are (1) set out all the starting conditions (e.g. "let his distance to school = d, let walking speed = s", etc) and (2) draw a diagram to better understand what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

When he goes to school, he takes time $t_1$ to travel a distance $d$. We can write this distance in terms of velocities, $v_w$ and $v_r$ (for walking and running):
$$d=v_w\frac{t_1}2+v_r\frac{t_1}2=\frac{v_w+v_r}2t_1$$
We now use a similar approach to calculate the time $t_2$ it takes to return from school. It takes $\frac d{2}\frac1{v_w}$ to walk, and $\frac d{2}\frac1{v_r}$ to run, so $$t_2= \frac d{2}\frac1{v_w}+\frac d{2}\frac1{v_r}$$
From these two equations you can find the ratio. Just plug in $d$ from the first into the second.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio is $4/9$.

Kobie's speed of walking, is, say, $v$ km per hour. So his running speed is $2v$ km per hour. Suppose the distance from Kobie's home to school is $d$ km. Assume it takes him $T$ hours to get to school. Let's say that $d_1$ is the distance Kobie covers while walking on his way to school, and $d_2$ is the distance Kobie covers while running on his way to school. Then $d_1+d_2=d$, and 
$$T/2=d_1/v=d_2/(2v)$$
hence $d_1=d_2/2$, so $d=3d_1$.
On his way back from school, the time it takes him to cover half the distance while running is $(d/2)/(v/2)=d/v$, and the time it takes him to the other half of the distance while walking, is $(d/2)/v$. Hence the ratio of times is
$$\frac{2d_1/v}{(d/v+(d/(2v))}=\frac{2d_1}{d+d/2}=\frac{2d_1}{3d_1+3d_1/2}=\frac{2}{3+3/2}=\frac{2}{9/2}=\frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: Small error: it seems like you use more time to run than to walk the half distance. The velocity for running is $2v$ not $v/2$, so the time for that segment is $d/(4v)$ not $d/v$. The final answer is $8/9$